# Delete object items from an array

Tags: javascript

I have an `object` element and an `array` element which contains some items of the `object`.

I would like to delete the items in the object referenced by the array.

```
var array = ["test1","test2"];

var object =     

   ...
"test1": {
    "na": [
        "t",
        "t-t",
        "t-98",
        "t"
    ]
},
"test2": {
    "python": [
        "jjj"
    ]
}

 ...
```

When I use

```
delete object.test1
```

It works.

However in my case, I want :

```
for(var  i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    delete object.array[i];
}
```

But I got :

> object.array is undefined

Any ideas ?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq3ahfow/)

Comment: it is because your `object` object does not have a property named `array`, it is an independent array object, and does not have anything to do with your `object` object. That is why you get the error.

Comment: `object.array[i];` should be `object[array[i]]`.

Comment: what's the difference between them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `object[array[i]]`, object.array does not exist

If you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) or underscore you can also use the `_.omit` function.

`object = _.omit( object, array )`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use array object notation.

`delete object[array[i]]`

Array notation is the only way to retrieve property values if you are indexing using a string value.